# JSF actionListener not called when View/Request scoped but only when Session

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, scope

**Given**: a primefaces 5.3 application with the following xhtml

```
    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:messages id="serversMessages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:selectOneListbox value="#{servers.model.selectedServer}" style="min-width:300px">
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{servers.onServerSelected}" update=":form" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{servers.model.servers}" var="srv" itemValue="#{srv.serverInfoId}" itemLabel="#{srv.name}" />
        </p:selectOneListbox>

        <p:column><p:inputText value="#{servers.model.edit.name}" /></p:column>
        <p:commandButton id="newServerBtn" actionListener="#{servers.onNewServerClicked}" value="New" update=":form"></p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton id="updServerBtn" disabled="#{empty servers.model.selectedServer}" actionListener="#{servers.onSaveClicked}" value="Save" update=":form"></p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton id="tmpServerBtn" actionListener="#{servers.onTempClicked}" value="Temp2" update=":form"></p:commandButton>

    </h:form>
```

**When**: I click on the updServerBtn (it's enabled when an item in the list has been selected)

**Expectation**: The backing bean method will be called.

**But actually**: The backing bean method is NOT called.

**Observations**:

1. If I remove the disabled property the backing bean is called.
2. The tmpServerBtn invokes a backing bean method.
3. When I click on the updServerBtn, an XHR happens with a 200 response.
4. The bean does not work properly when it is View or Request scoped but does work at the Session scoped level.

**Analysis**:

It would seem like that Primefaces is deciding that it is not worthwhile to call the backing bean method.

**Similar Questions**

Before posting my question, I did find this post here:

[commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked)

When I remove the disabled attribute of the updServerBtn, the backing bean method **does** get invoked.  This suggests to me that the possible causes of problems in the above post, probably don't apply.

Comment: I submitted this question last week and it was marked as a duplicate of the existing question, however I feel that is not the case.

Comment: Do you have correct import for `@ViewScoped`?

Comment: Current the application uses the Scoped annotations in the javax.faces.bean package.

Comment: And your managed bean is `@ManagedBean`?

Comment: Did you search on actions not being called in combination with the disabled attribute? Several topics to on SO

Comment: So your view scoped managed bean is reconstructed on every request (just put debug breakpoint in postconstruct to verify), and it's basically behaving like a request scoped one? That's a different problem: you're actually not using a view scoped bean as answered in that dupe.

Comment: @BalusC I think you are correct, that this was probably point #5 on the referenced question.  I probably made some kind of error when I said that I tried ViewScoped.

Answer (score -1):

I did the following to get things to work:

1. I made the managed bean ViewScoped
2. I made the disabled property of the save button a simple boolean
   field.  (Rather than an expression to be resolved by JSF or the
   backing bean, I don't know if that mattes)

Comment: what is a simple boolean field? Seems like you 'fixed' something without actually knowing what you do/did. In that case, this Q and A is totally useless to others (at least the A is). You problem is like @BalusC stated in the last comment above.